# UIWebView localication

Tags: ios, localization, uiwebview

I'm developing multi languages application and intent to have DONE button localized. This button is appear in UIWebView when user clicked on dropdown ("select" tag) with multiselect:

[image]

By default, this is always in English. However, if you set CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations to YES in .plist file, you will be able to get it in current **SYSTEM** language:

[image]

Here, DONE is written in Chinese, when text in select in Arabic. It is because current system languages (i.e. set in Settings) is Chinese, but inside app I selected Arabic so app is using Arabic bundle with Arabic strings file.

I wonder, is any possibility to localize "DONE" button to current **Application's** language, but not **system** language?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "Application's language". Simply use the system language, like all other applications do.

I'm sure it's possible to somehow achieve it, but you're simply taking the wrong approach to localization.